# I'am having some problems with boost json in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, object, boost

I see that have a lot of questions very similar to mine, but I don´t see any solutions that fit with my problem.

I' am trying to create a JSON with boost library with the below structure:

```
{
  "event_date": "2018-06-11T09:35:48.867Z",
  "event_log": "2018-06-11 09:35:43,253 - recycler [TRACE]: Running recycler::WITHDRAW",
  "cassettes": [
      {
          "value" : "0",
          "currency": "BRL",
          "CDMType" : "WFS_CDM_TYPEREJECTCASSETTE",
          "lppPhysical" : [
              {
                  "positionName" : "BIN1A",
                  "count" : "3"
              }
          ]
      },
      {.....},{.....}
    ]
}
```

Below we will have the code that I have now:

```
boost::property_tree::ptree children, children2, child, child1, child2, child3, child4, child5, cassettes;

child1.put("value", "cash_unit->ulValues");
child2.put("currency", "std::string(cash_unit->cCurrencyID).substr(0, 3)");
child3.put("CDMType", "cash_unit->usType");

child4.put("lppPhysical.positionName", "ph_unit->lpPhysicalPositionName");
child5.put("lppPhysical.count", "cash_unit->ulCount");

cassettes.put("event_date", "2018-06-11T09:35:48.867Z");
cassettes.put("event_log", "2018-06-11 09:35:43,253 - recycler [TRACE]: Running recycler::WITHDRAW");

children.push_back(std::make_pair("", child1));
children.push_back(std::make_pair("", child2));
children.push_back(std::make_pair("", child3));

children2.push_back(std::make_pair("", child4));
children2.push_back(std::make_pair("", child5));

cassettes.add_child("cassettes", children);

write_json("C:\\Temp\\test.json", cassettes);`
```

Summarizing, I'm having difficulties to put an array of objects inside of an array of objects.

Comment: Hi Allan Paz, from your question, it is not clear what the problem is; could you specify what goes wrong? (error message, wrong output...) so it is easier for other people to answer your question?

Comment: Sure, I'm having difficulties to insert an array (the lppPhysical) inside the cassettes (array of objects) like the above structure. My code only inserts the IppPhysical as an object in the cassettes.

Comment: This is still unclear... Am I then correct in assuming that the structure you posted is your current output and that it is not what you want? If so could you please post the desired output?

Comment: The mentioned structure is the correct one(mock), I need to translate this structure using boost library, but I am having difficulties on the lppPhysical part(Insert an array of objects as a child of the cassettes, which is an array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution to my case, it's pretty simple but was hard to find since I am not too familiar with this library.

```
        //LppPhysical insertion
        lppPhysicalInfo.put("positionName", ph_unit->lpPhysicalPositionName);
        lppPhysicalInfo.put("count", cash_unit->ulCount);
        lppPhysical.push_back(std::make_pair("", lppPhysicalInfo));

        //Cassettes insertions
        cassettesInfo.put("value", cash_unit->ulValues);
        cassettesInfo.put("currency", std::string(cash_unit->cCurrencyID).substr(0, 3));
        cassettesInfo.put("CDMType", cash_unit->usType);
        cassettesInfo.add_child("lppPhysical", lppPhysical.get_child(""));
        cassettes.push_back(std::make_pair("", cassettesInfo));

        //External information insertion
        arquivo.put("event_date", "DateValue");
        arquivo.put("event_log", "LogValue");
        arquivo.add_child("cassettes", cassettes);

        //Json creator
        write_json("C:\\Temp\\assassino.json", arquivo);
```

On the lppPhysical I just make a pair with all its content and on the Cassettes' insertion I just added the lppPhysical as a child of the cassettes and that's it. Now the lppPhysical is an array of object insde the Cassettes which is also an array of objects